# How to retrieve unique count of a field using Kibana + Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Is it possible to query for a distinct/unique count of a field using Kibana? I am using elastic search as my backend to Kibana.

If so, what is the syntax of the query? Heres a link to the Kibana interface I would like to make my query: http://demo.kibana.org/#/dashboard

I am parsing nginx access logs with logstash and storing the data into elastic search.  Then, I use Kibana to run queries and visualize my data in charts.  Specifically, I want to know the count of unique IP addresses for a specific time frame using Kibana.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

*For Kibana 4 go to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26534372/1004046)*

This is easy to do with a terms panel:

[image: Adding a terms panel to Kibana]

If you want to select the count of distinct IP that are in your logs, you should specify in the field `clientip`, you should put a big enough number in length (otherwise, it will join different IP under the same group) and specify in the style table. After adding the panel, you will have a table with IP, and the count of that IP:

[image: Table with IP and count]

Comment: Is it possible to get a count of unique term(ex. IP)? if that is possible what about graphing that into time interval, so to determine # of unique term per day? Thanks

Comment: @Klu You can get the unique count of the IPs, and you can set a timestamp filter with a custom day to get the count of each IP in that day. What you cannot do, it is to show a graph with multiple days and the unique count of the different terms on each day.

Comment: How do I use kibana+elastic search to get the unique count of IPs? Thanks for the quick response

Comment: Now, if only dates weren't converted to longs for some reason. It'd be nice to have a table layout detailing counts for, say, the last 10 days or whatever.

Comment: @Pigueiras "What you cannot do, it is to show a graph with multiple days and the unique count of the different terms on each day" My problem now - isn't a simple splunk like time chart like that supported in Kibana? I have a question about it here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26141659/how-to-create-value-over-time-chart-with-non-numeric-value-with-kibana-3

Comment: @Klu If you are still interested I posted: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26534372/1004046 for Kibana 4

Comment: FWIW, "big enough number in length" just needs to be larger than the largest value expected for each component of an IP. 1000 works for my usage. Specifying a value of 1000000 broke the widget on my machine.

Comment: If you simply want a distinct count of a field using the terms panel, I suggest setting the "Length" of the panel to 0 and ensure that the "Other" option is enabled. After this, Kibana will show the distinct count of your field in the "Other" row in your terms panel. This is great for getting the value to answer specific questions about your data, but not so great for building dashboards.

Answer (score 48):

Now Kibana 4 allows you to use aggregations. Apart from building a panel like the one that was explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21836761/1004046) for Kibana 3, now we can see the number of unique IPs in different periods, that was (IMO) what the OP wanted at the first place.

To build a dashboard like this you should go to Visualize -> Select your Index -> Select a Vertical Bar chart and then in the visualize panel:

- In the Y axis we want the unique count of IPs (select the field where you stored the IP) and in the X axis we want a date histogram with our timefield.

[image: Building a visualization]

- After pressing the *Apply* button, we should have a graph that shows the unique count of IP distributed on time. We can change the time interval on the X axis to see the unique IPs hourly/daily...

[image: Final plot]

Just take into account that the unique counts are **[approximate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html#_counts_are_approximate)**. For more information check also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33627186/1004046).

Answer (score 8):

Be aware with Unique count you are using 'cardinality' metric, which does not always guarantee exact unique count. :-)

> the cardinality metric is an approximate algorithm. It is based on the
>   HyperLogLog++ (HLL) algorithm. HLL works by hashing your input and
>   using the bits from the hash to make probabilistic estimations on the
>   cardinality.

Depending on amount of data I can get differences of 700+ entries missing in a 300k dataset via Unique Count in Elastic which are otherwise really unique.

Read more here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/cardinality.html

Answer (score 6):

Create "topN" query on "clientip" and then histogram with count on "clientip" and set "topN" query as source. Then you will see count of different ips per time.

Comment: nice tip for Kibana 3 :)

Comment: but we can no longe store clientip in elasticsearch due to GDPR , how can we store the md5 hash instead?

Answer (score 3):

Unique counts of field values are achieved by using facets. See [ES documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/facets/) for the full story, but the gist is that you will create a query and then ask ES to prepare facets on the results for counting values found in fields. It's up to you to customize the fields used and even describe how you want the values returned. The most basic of facet types is just to group by terms, which would be like an IP address above. You can get pretty complex with these, even requiring a query within your facet!

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "facets": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "ip_address"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but Im interested in knowing how to make this query using Kibana as my interface to elastic search.  Heres a link to a Kibana dashboard: http://demo.kibana.org/#/dashboard.  How can you make the query you mentioned in this dashboard?

Comment: Ah, sorry about that.

Comment: facets are now deprecated and aggregation is now replacement in ES

Answer (score 2):

For **Kibana 7.x**, `Unique Count` is available in most visualizations.

For example, in **Lens**:

[image]

In **aggregation** based visualizations:

[image]

And even in **TSVB** (supporting normal fields as well as Runtime Fields, Scripted Fields are not supported):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using Aggs u can easily do that.
Writing down query for now.

```
GET index/_search
{
  "size":0,
  "aggs": {
    "source": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "field",
        "size": 100000
      }
    }
  }
 }
```

This would return the different values of `field` with there doc counts.