# How to create value over time chart with non numeric value with Kibana 3?

Tags: string, histogram, kibana, splunk

I want to create a simple time chart in Kibana 3, with a non numeric value, ie create a chart with "number of each actorname per day over one week". How can i do it in Kibana? In Splunk it's easy with the time chart, but Kibanas Histogram doesn't seem to work with non numeric values - I guess the historgram is what i want.

EDIT: Correct answer is in the comments - you can't do this in Kibana 3

Comment: It is not possible with the current version of Kibana (3.1 at the moment of speaking). You need aggregation to perform such operation in ES (date + terms aggregation), but Kibana doesn't provide that feature.

Comment: Try a TopN query.  (I can't find a direct link, sorry).

Comment: Thanks for the correct answer Pigueiras, that's what I found on the net too, but I wanted to be sure. Sadly, I have to use Splunk then.

Comment: Some admin might wanna put Pigueiras answer as the correct answer!