# Kibana dashboard: term panel

Tags: dashboard, kibana, panels

Is it possible to change the name of term column in the term panel table?

Example, in the term image in the question:
[How to retrieve unique count of a field using Kibana + Elastic Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102220/how-to-retrieve-unique-count-of-a-field-using-kibana-elastic-search)

As you can see the term panel (which has no title here) has three columns: term, count, action.

I would like to change the word term into something else. Is it possible?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I just went to the source html code file of the term panel and changed it. Too simple..