# Retrieve count of values for searched string in column using Elastic Search + Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Question is similar to this one([How to retrieve unique count of a field using Kibana + Elastic Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102220/how-to-retrieve-unique-count-of-a-field-using-kibana-elastic-search) )

In my case, data in graph should be count of values from one specific column. 
For example, I have a column named 'Link' with data:

```
www.example.com
www.example.com?country=us
www.example.com?country=eng
www.example.com?country=jap
www.example.com?countr=us
```

So the question is, how to search in column Link only those that have '?country' string and then list those by number.

```
country=us  | 2
country=eng | 1
country=jap | 1
```

UPDATE:

Looks like you can't search for a string in string and then to let Kibana transform your data into graph or table on it's own. Check Alains response to solve it differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step would be to use 'grok' to pull the country value into its own field.  Then you can use that on a terms panel in kibana to show you the frequency.

Comment: Thank you for your response! It isn't quite as expected, never thought about using grok, but it did put me on the right path to solve the problem.