# Missing data when using unique count and creating an aggregation in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I have a behavior in Kibana, I can't explain. The following is a simple bar chart, counting unique users, filtered by application and a role, and ensuring certain fields exist on the logs:

[image]

This graph shows that I have approx. 170 users which have the role 'Landmand'. If I split the bar by the term 'fields.Role', I would expect a identical chart, since I already applied a filter specifying 'fields.Role:Landmand' in the search. However I see this.

[image: Bar chat split by term]

This suddenly limits the unique count to approx. 150 users. I've tried with different fields and it seems to have the same behavior - as soon as I split the bar, I seem to limit the data somehow.

Any information is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It happens because it uses the [cardinality aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html) to do the unique count. As it is explained in the link, the count is approximate and it has a % of error. Just do a quick test, try to copy the request and try with a different precision threshold to see the difference.

To set a custom `precision_threshold` you can use the advanced section and put a custom JSON Input to the aggregation:

[image: Adding a precision threshold to the aggregation]

If you go to the *Request* section, you can actually see that the threshold has been added to the cardinality aggregation.

[image]

Comment: Wow - I didn't know that. Thanks. Pretty large error percentage of 35% in this case.

Comment: Side note - do you know if it is possible to set this in a visualization via json input field?

Comment: @jaspernygaard Are you asking if it's possible to set the precision threshold in Kibana?

Comment: Yes, either directly in a visualization via the json input field in Kibana4 or globally in ES.