# Kibana-Group by a field

Tags: json, kibana, kibana-5

I have a field like `HW-OS Version`,`HW-RiskRatio`,`Device_HW_Count` and there are some `HW_Version` say `A,B,C,A` and their risk ratio as `200,300,100,400`.Now using Kibana if i try to show the count and the risk ratio i get the output in the above format whereas I want the output as grouping by the `HW_version` field,which Kibana is not able to do.I read in the documentation that for such cases we need to write Json query which could do the grouping like a SQL query.Can someone please explain me this with the above example.I am not able to proceed forward

Comment: What type of graph are you having?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try doing the `aggregation` using the `Terms` option in a **Bar Graph** for example, where you can select the field `HW_version`, and then maybe you can have your filters as `sub-buckets` according to your need, so that your graph would be based on a `group by` of the field you selected.

i.e: The Y Axis would be having the count (risk ratio), and the X Axis would be divided according to your field `HW_version` which should be having bars for (A,B,C). This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102220/how-to-retrieve-unique-count-of-a-field-using-kibana-elastic-search/26534372#26534372) could be helpful.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your solution.I am not using Bar graph here ,I am using a data grid where I am trying to represent the above data in a group by method.

Comment: So even in a `data grid`, you can still have the `terms aggregation`, where you might need to have the filters separately for the values of `HW_version`.